# Why the Ubuntu 13.10 Beta 1 ISO files are so big?

Tags: iso

I was considering downloading the Ubuntu 13.10 Beta 1 ISO file just to check out the new thing, but when you access the [download page](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/13.10/beta-1/source/) you see an 4.5 GB file available for download, so I got confused and curious. What is the reason for a so big ISO file if when it's released its size is reduced to almost 700 mb (CD size)?

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked to contains the iso images for the source code as well. The normal distribution comes along only with the compiled binaries, not the source code. What you're looking for is [this](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/). And btw the beta for regular ubuntu is still unavailable as of now. What you can get are the daily build images.